# Ignore some Flask routes in Opentelemetry

Tags: python, flask, open-telemetry

I have a generic `flask` application.  The application is instrumented using `opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask`, I am shipping this data with the `opentelemetry-exporter-otlp` to an Elastic `APM` server.  This is all working fine and it is done as [the documentation](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#instrumentation-example-with-flask) shows.

There are some endpoints of the application that I would like **not to track** with the instrumentation, as they are noisy and add little-to-no value for me (For example, health endpoints).  I want the instrumentation to ignore them, but I cannot find how.

How can this be done?  I have been checking [the documentation for Python](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and after searching over the internet, I could not find any clear answer about how this could be done... because I believe this *must be doable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using environment variable `OTEL_PYTHON_FLASK_EXCLUDED_URLS`. It takes a comma separated regular expressions for urls you want to exclude. For more detailed info please check here https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask#exclude-lists